# The Ubuntu App Showdown -Specific software

Tags: application-development

I would like to participate the contest but I'm programming very specific scientific tools for the work in a molecular biological lab. I know that I won't win with such an app but it's a nice possibility to get into Qickly and Ubuntu Apps since I'm only programming for Windows at the moment.

My question is, whether I have a possibility to explain what my software is doing and for what it is good in the lab. Also I have to provide some test data, that the jury can try it out. Is this possible and how I can submit those additional information?

Comment: How can you say that scientific app wont win in the contest . I am still waiting for good scientific apps .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd very much encourage you to submit your app!

In terms of describing your app, it is really up to you how you spread the word about it, but here are a couple of suggestions:

- When you're submitting the application to [MyApps](http://myapps.developer.com), add the information to the feedback form for the reviewers.
- Write a blog post about your app, and submit it to the [Ubuntu App Showdown reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/UbuntuAppShowdown).

I'd personally recommend the second, as it's going to give much more visibility to your app.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement, I finally submited:
http://redd.it/wa5fe

Comment: Great, remember to submit it to myapps.developer.ubuntu.com as described on Step 4 on http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown !